# What screws should I have used for drywall? (And can I fix this situation?)

Tags: drywall, screws, fastener

I'm installing an [IKEA Bjurstra wall-mounted table](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/80217524/).

The primary load-bearer is the vertical column, and I've successfully fastened this to a wood stud using 2x #12x2 pan head drill screws:

[image]

But the same screws applied to the braces that keep the table flush to the wall, ended up only stripping the dry wall:

[image]

So now, though the vertical column is holding up the table just fine, the screws on the braces are loose and hanging out.

[image]

1. What kind of screws should I have used?
2. Aside from starting over and installing the table at a different height, what can I do to amend this situation?

I am not a DIY-savvy person, so I would prefer ease or convenience over cost-savings. Thank you.

Comment: Or, did the drywall strip because of how I screwed things in? I used a power drill to first drill a pilot hole, then the power drill again to screw in the screws with moderate but not strong pressure.This actually seemed to have worked for 1 of the 4 screws, but the rest stripped.

Comment: Next time, try and find the nearest stud - a vertical strip of timber holding up the plasterboard - and screw into that instead, if it is close enough. Otherwise, as noted, use a "readi-driver" or any other type of plasterboard anchor (not just a rawl-plug - they don't have enough holding power for plasterboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree that you want some dry-wall anchors. Just running a screw into drywall has absolutely no holding power - you need to get something with a very coarse thread, or an anchor that goes through the wall and holds it from the rear side.

Whatever you select, look for the load rating, and divide by 4 for the maximum weight of table and its loading. I prefer [Toggler metal connectors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-30-Pack-0-25-in-x-2-5-in-Yellow-Zinc-Toggle-Bolts/3183849) (these have a 265lb rating in drywall - and I doubt that the table and contents will weigh more than 66lb).

To install these you need a 1/2" drill bit - so you can reuse the holes you've already drilled for the screws that Bjursta'd out.

Answer (score 4):

I expect you want some kind of wall plug. You would take the table down, install the wall plugs (which generally need a bigger hole than screws so your exiting screwholes shouldn't be an issue) and then screw the shelf to the wall plugs.

Here in the UK I would look at something like [this](http://www.diy.com/departments/rawlplug-metal-plastic-wall-plug-screw-pack-of-12/254291_BQ.prd?ecamp=Seapla&ppc_type=shopping&ds_kids=92700014229473832&gclid=CKahkeGku9ACFVUo0wod9K0ECQ&dclid=COOpgOKku9ACFQww0wodFCMPKQ), but i'm not sure how american drywall compares to our plasterboard (also not sure if that one is the right size, I generally judge sizes of such things by eye rather than measurements).

Comment: Here is an American equivalent.  The term is wall anchor or screw anchor.  There are other types, but I do like these.
http://www.homedepot.com/p/E-Z-Ancor-Twist-N-Lock-75-lb-Medium-Duty-Drywall-Anchors-50-Pack-25310/100040265